# Is $\frac{\sigma^2_{\mathbf{MLE}}-\sigma^2}{\mathbf{se}(\sigma_{\mathbf{MLE}}^2)}$ asymptotically normal?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, estimators

Let $\mathbf{X}=\{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n\}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $\mu$ is known. Does $\frac{\sigma^2_{\mathbf{MLE}}-\sigma^2}{\mathbf{se}(\sigma_{\mathbf{MLE}}^2)}$ is asymptotically normal  and why?
I know $$\sigma_{\mathbf{MLE}}^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[X_i-\mu\right]^2$$
and $\frac{n\sigma_{\mathbf{MLE}}^2}{\sigma^2}\sim\chi^2(n-1)$.

Comment: it is asymptotically normal because it is a mean of (assuming you meant independent) random variables with finite variances.

Comment: @JohnMadden What's the support, all of $\mathbb R$ or something else?

Comment: @Dave the domain of random variables in a sequence need not agree with the domain of the random variable they are converging to; consider for example $\hat{\rho} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i} X_i$ with $X_i\sim\textrm{bernoulli}(\rho)$. But I was trying to address the OP's newest edits, where we consider the distribution of the difference between the estimate and the truth (which can indeed be positive or negative).

Comment: To appreciate the subtleties lurking here, consider the version of this question where it is known only that $\sigma^2 \ge 1.$  The asymptotic distribution of this statistic is *not* Normal when in fact $\sigma^2 \le 1.$  But the "usual regularity conditions" for MLE imply that when the parameter is not on the boundary of its space, you do have asymptotic Normality--not because the MLE is a mean, but ultimately because the *log likelihood* is a sum of *iid* variables. (If the SE is estimated, an additional step is needed, but the idea remains the same.)